# What share of Donald Trump's voters in 2016 voted for George Bush in 2004?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, voter-turnout, george-w-bush

Donald J. Trump (DJT) received roughly 63 million votes in 2016. Geroge W. Bush (GWB) received 62 million votes in 2004. At the same time the US Population has grown from 293 to 322 million people (not necessary the population eligible to vote). On a map the coalitions look similar, also the demographic composition looks similar (see (ropercenter.cornell) and [here](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/11/09/how-the-faithful-voted-a-preliminary-2016-analysis/) (Pew)).

Also, I'd like to exclude everyone who is younger than 30 in 2016 (the voting age is 18, everyone who is younger than 30 couldn't vote in 2004). People who are dead in 2016 but voted for GWB, are excluded by the scope of this question, because I'm  only interested in one direction: DJT's voter who voted for GWB; not GWB's voter who voted for DJT.

So the question is: given a DJT's voter in 2016, what is the probability that they voted for GWB in 2004 (based on polling, statistics, voting registers, ...)?

A starting point is [this analysis between Barack Obama and DJT](http://www.rasmussenreports.com/public_content/political_commentary/commentary_by_geoffrey_skelley/just_how_many_obama_2012_trump_2016_voters_were_there) (Rasmussen). The bottom line is, that Barack Obama received a lot of votes and roughly 10% voted for DJT, but "it would not be surprising if Obama’s percentage were somewhat inflated and Romney’s a bit diminished". Is there a similar analysis between DJT and GWB?

Comment: This seems to be [a Speculative question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/what-custom-close-reasons-should-we-have/3098#3098). It could be answerable if there are statistics to back it up, but not regarding the analysis of the possibility since we won't exactly know.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question to improve it; but why is it speculative to ask if the voting behaviour has changed between the last and the current republican presidents? in fact, this seems like to be an important question.

Comment: The issue is the wording of the question. If you ask for polls that explored that relationship it is ok, if you ask us to opinate about how likely that relationship is then it is off-topic. As you express it, it seems the former.

Comment: I don't have an answer to this, but I suspect that [FiveThirtyEight](https://fivethirtyeight.com/politics) has the answer somewhere.

Comment: Trende and Byler of RealClearPolitics write about how the [county level results have shifted](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/articles/2017/01/20/how_trump_won_--_conclusions_132846.html).  The challenge with individuals is that that information is confidential.  So at best we'd have polling data that might be incorrect (people remember their votes differently than they cast them; or just lie to pollsters).

Comment: No. Those three open-data surveys (covered in Rasmussen's) didn't ask about voting for Bush; I checked them individually. So there's no "starting point" in answering your question unless you plan to commision your own survey. The last survey http://www.centerforpolitics.org/crystalball/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Trump_voter_poll_crosstabs.pdf does have correlation with bush sympathizers "favaorable opinion of". When Stackexchange manages to fix its imgur problem, I'll upload the relevant page(s).

Comment: @SJuan76 I think the question (headline) is sufficient. It's essentially trying to summarize the entirety of the OP's question (body). The OP set parameters requiring the exclusion of people younger than 30 and people who died between 2004 and 2016. However, it is a difficult question to even begin answering. Overall, there's a lot of data that would need to be found before an answer could be attempted.

Answer (score 1):

Since the actual (non-provisional) ballots cast are anonymous, it's not possible to answer the question with anything other than a guess based on polls or surveys.  And, since the pre-election polls did not look much like the election results, we can all surmise that the accuracy regarding the shared/overlap of voters would be incorrect as well.